# 'emulator: command not found' after restart my Macbook

Tags: android, macos

I spend two days to download the android source code and compiled it then I turn off my mac book and go to sleep, but today when I wake up and open my computer, I typed `$ emulator`, comes `emulator: command not found`. someone help me, please!

[image]

[image]

Comment: Did you add it to the environment variables? Was it just downloaded, or was it installed?

Comment: yeah, it would help to know why you expected it to work.